# What integration technique to use?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2+2x+5}\; $$

Is there a way to solve this integral without performing u-substitution and using the common integral for arctan?

Comment: Why two dx's?  Anything special?

Comment: what about completing square and then using arctan? Avoiding the use of arctan could be a bit tough

Comment: Let me clarify that last comment further: are we allowed to use $\arctan$ at all, or do you want a completely different method?

Comment: Common arctan integral should be avoided.

Comment: To avoid $\arctan$, you could perform partial fraction decomposition. Of course, that will lead to complex $\ln$'s, which is really only a fancy rewriting of $\arctan$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\frac1{x^2+2x+5}=\frac1{8i}\left(\frac1{x+1-4i}-\frac1{x+1+4i}\right)$$

Now use complex logarithms and the complex definition of arctan.

---

Alternatively, we can use the geometric series:

$$\frac1{x^2+2x+5}=\frac{1/4}{1+\frac{(x+1)^2}4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x+1)^{2n}}{4^{n+1}}$$

And now it's a simple integration term by term, though this does not lend you closed forms nicely.

---

Remark:  You should probably use arctangents when you can, because things get messy otherwise.

Comment: I just posted a comment about this myself, but it seems that the OP wants to avoid arctan

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Fixed it?  :-(

Comment: I mean, I guess so... what you've done is really more of a technicality XD but we will see if the OP likes it more. My guess is that if the OP isn't comfortable with arctan substitution he/she is DEFINITELY not going to be comfortable with the complex form, but only time will tell. I'll throw a +1 your way regardless :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Lol, I definitely feel the same way.  Complex arctangents coming from logarithms of complex numbers... not something I would enjoy.

Comment: (+1) for the first way forward.  Note that the series expansion should be an alternating series.

Comment: @Dr.MVthanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

While it's trivial to transform this series into something much simpler, as we can see here
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2+2x+5}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2+4}$$
$$=\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x^2+4} \operatorname*{=}^{x \to 1/x} \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{dx}{4x^2+1}$$
The important thing is that the answer to your integral is $\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2)-\frac{\pi}{8}$
Note that there is ***NO*** simpler closed form for $\arctan(2)$

*(except perhaps in terms of complex logarithms which is more of a technicality)*